# Table's id is replaced by the foreign key's id

Tags: react-native, sqlite, expo

I am using Expo's SQLite module in my react native project. I have two tables, (messages and users):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
    id text not null,
    sender_id integer,
    thread_id integer,
    body text,
    foreign key (sender_id) references users (id),
    foreign key (thread_id) references threads (id)
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id integer primary key,
    first_name text,
    last_name text,
    email text
);
```

And if I insert some messages:

```
INSERT INTO messages (id, sender_id, thread_id, body) values ('xeieoef-ee, 3, 1, 'test');
INSERT INTO messages (id, sender_id, thread_id, body) values ('ttrefzr-ry, 3, 1, 'payload');
```

I would like to get all messages including its user's data by comparing the thread id's. This is how I am querying:

```
select * from messages, users where thread_id = 2 AND messages.sender_id = users.id;
```

However, this results in both the message id and user id to be the same:

```
[
    {
      "body": "test",
      "email": "userthree@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "userThreeF",
      "id": 3,
      "last_name": "threeUserL",
      "sender_id": 3,
      "thread_id": 1,
    },
    {
      "body": "payload",
      "email": "userthree@gmail.com",
      "first_name": "userThreeF",
      "id": 3,
      "last_name": "threeUserL",
      "sender_id": 3,
      "thread_id": 1,
    },
]
```

Instead of message's id to have its own id, the message's id is the sender's id. What am I doing wrong here?

**Update code**

I have a button in the app which `onpress` sends the data to the `MessageStore`'s function.

```
sendText = () => {
    const {MessageStore, UserStore, SocketStore} = this.props;
    const data = {
        id: uuid.v4(),
        sender_id: UserStore.userInfo.user.id,
        thread_id: 1,
        body: this.state.text,
    }
    MessageStore.addMessageToDB(data);
}
```

On the store, the message is added to the database by the `addMessageToDB()`, which again calls the `getMessageFromDatabase()` to get all the messages.

```
@action addMessageToDB = (payload) => {
    db.transaction(
        tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `INSERT INTO messages
                    (id, sender_id, thread_id, body, status) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?);`,
                [payload.id, payload.sender_id, payload.thread_id, payload.body, "pending"],
                (tx, results) => {
                    console.log('message insertion success')
                },
                (tx, error) => console.log('message insertion error', error)
            );
            this.getMessageFromDatabase(payload.thread_id);
        }
    )
}

@action getMessageFromDatabase = (payload) => {
    console.log('>>> getMessageFromDatabase payload', payload);
    db.transaction(
        tx => {
            tx.executeSql(
                `select * from messages inner join users on messages.sender_id=users.id where thread_id = ?;`, [payload],
                (tx, {rows}) => {
                    console.log('inner join success', rows._array);
                },
                (tx, error) => console.log('inner join error', error),
            );
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I have tried to replicate the code in snack and I have the same results. Heres the [expo link](https://snack.expo.io/Hy9l69jo-)

Comment: @Kakar Yes! That's it. No idea what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Edit with solution:

Both tables have an 'id' column, so the user id is overwriting the message id.

This worked: `select messages.*, users.first_name, users.last_name, users.email from messages inner join users on messages.sender_id=users.id where thread_id = ?;`

Comment: Sorry, but this has the same results.

Comment: We'll need to see some code then, I don't think there's anything wrong with what you've posted here

Comment: Hi! I have updated the question with the relevant code. Could you please have a look.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong. Can you make a minimal example that replicates the issue on snack.expo.io ?

Comment: Interesting. I have tried to replicate the code in snack and I have the same results. Heres the [expo link](https://snack.expo.io/Hy9l69jo-)

Comment: I can't have a proper look right now but the resultSet.insertId is giving an int for the message insertion transactions, not the text I'd. So it's being inserted wrong. Could it be something to do with the primary_key constraint?

Comment: @Lucas I think its not that. I have also tested it with the primary key as integer. Here's the [expo snack link](https://snack.expo.io/BJ1BoAjo-)